# How to find curved superspace vielbein and connection?

Tags: supersymmetry, supergravity

Need help with finding total curved superspace vielbein and connection in terms of SUGRA multiplet components (graviton, gravitino, auxiliary real vector and complex scalar). In Wess and Bagger textbook they give only $\theta=\bar{\theta}=0$ components, so I need to find higher components in $\theta$ and $\bar{\theta}$. A good reference (as thorough as possible) would also help.

From torsion, for example, we get $D_ME_N^A\pm D_NE_M^A$ ($D$ - superspace covariant derivative, $E$ - superspace vielbein, M, N, A are superspace indices), but I need another equation to obtain derivatives of the vielbein separately. That would give me $\theta$, $\bar{\theta}$ components.

Comment: This question could use more context to make it more accessible. You should always define your notation (What is $D$? What is $E$? I could guess it, but clearly stating it is always preferable), and, if possible, give short explanations of what you're trying to do. From *what given data* ("SUGRA multiplet components" is a bit vague) do you want to find exactly *what other quantities*?

Comment: Added more info, hope that clears things.